# Available options for editing remote files without uploading

Tags: command-line-interface, files, remote, graphical-user-interface

**Objective:** Edit remote files that are either too large to upload or can't be moved outside of the host environment.

I've heard people mention the `vim` editor (or `nano`/`pico` etc.) when it comes to editing remote files over ssh. However, I'm unaware (and curious) of any other ways to do this.

What are some other ways of achieving this, perhaps even through a GUI program or at least without ssh+local-editor.

*Which option is best for less powerful servers like say a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Did you really intend to say you are using a Raspberry Pi as **server**? It is certainly usable as a thin client, but it seems under-powered to be used as server? Are you using Linux on both client and server?

Comment: Yep, I use a raspberry Pi as a toy-server for small projects. It's quiet and low-powered (Mainly small Go http server). I use Ubuntu on my main machine. And ubuntu server on my servers.

Comment: This might get a better response on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many editors have SSH clients in them, so that you can connect to the remote server and edit files there. Actually they will download the file to your computer, you edit it there and it uploads the file back to the server.

And then, you can SSH to the box and use any text-based editor via the SSH connection.

The following two options are harder to implement in a secure way.

You can run an X11 server on your computer, and run the X11 based file editor so that it uses the X11 server running on your server to show the GUI.

You can have a file server running on the remote computer, and map the drive on your local computer.